# Datepicker não funciona

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Estou construindo um sistema no qual tenho que cadastrar plano de açoes, até aí tudo bem...

Na hora do cadastro existem três inputs, O quê, Quem e Quando conforme figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> O problema está quando eu clico no novo campo "Quando?", pois o datepicker não aparece novamente...
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código:**

***Script:***

```
<script>
    $.(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({});

        $(".inserirItens").on('click', function() {
            var inputs = "aqui eu defino o html dos meus inputs que vão ser adicionados posteriormente";
            $(this).closest('.form-group').append(inputs);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="oque" class="">
    <input type="text" name="quem" class="">
    <input type="text" name="quando" class="datepicker">
    <button class="inserirItens"><i class='icon icon-plus' ></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tente adicionar a função do inserirItens após o append o seguinte trecho: `$(this).closest('.form-group').find('#datepicker').datepicker({});` //Só trocar pelo id ou class específico ali no find; Assim cada item dinamicamente adicionado será trelado a função datepicker. O mesmo não funcionava pois você apenas inicializa o primeiro... e o resto que é criado dinamicamente não é atrelado ao datepicker.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft... não funcionou...tentei até colocar o :last, que é para ele pegar o último elemento com a class datepicker... mas sem resultado

Comment: Porque estás a passar um objeto vazio para o método `.datepicker();`? devia ser sem nada.

Comment: @Sergio depende, no meu caso eu não passo, mas isso não influencia no que está acontecendo

Comment: Poderia tentar algo como? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433154/putting-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-elements-jquery-jqueryui, assim cada input que for um datepicker e que receber focus ele vai especificar como `datepicker`. Código do link: `$('body').on('focus',".datepicker_recurring_start", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​`  Só mudar para a sua situação.

Comment: Use a solução que o @RafaelWithoeft postou, apenas mude o filtro do `find` por `.datepicker` e lembre de deixar o `append` antes: `$(this).closest('.form-group').append(inputs).find(".datepicker").datepicker({});`

Comment: RafaelWithoeft e Oeslei -> nada...

Comment: Como você monta esses inputs? Vem de outra página ou é fixo sempre no seu javascript?

Comment: @Tafarel_Brayan podes fazer um jsFiddle a reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, eu tenho no meu codigo os inputs montados dentro de uma div que esta com **display:none**, e toda vez que eu clico em inserir, eu vou nessa div e pego com o html() os inputs...

Comment: @Sergio, eu não tenho jsFiddle, mas vou fazer um e montar para vcs verem..

Comment: Tarafel poderia tentar talvez assim então?  `newDiv = myDiv.clone(true).insertAfter(mydest);  
    // attach datepickers by instance rather than by class
    newDiv.find('input.datefield').datepicker();` Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma...

```
$(".inserirItens").on('click', function() {
    var inputs = "aqui eu defino o html dos meus inputs que vão ser adicionados posteriormente";
    $(this).closest('.form-group').append(inputs);
    $(".inputDatepicker").datepicker("destroy");
    $(".inputDatepicker").datepicker("refresh");
});
```

> Só ainda não descobri o motivo pelo qual tenho que está a a todo tempo destruindo o datepicker e logo em seguida dando um refresh... mas solucionou meu caso

Fonte: [jqueryUi/Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('focus','.datepicker', function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: não deu certo assim...